# Why <amq:broker> is required?

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic

I'm checking one project code; in spring.xml I see that 'amq:broker' is configured  for input and output. Along with this configuration, ActiveMQConnectionFactory>PooledConnectionFactory>JmsConfiguration>ActiveMQComponent are also configured.

I need to know what is 'broker' element and why it is required and how it is different from 'brokerURL' of ActiveMQConnectionFactory.

'Broker' section of http://activemq.apache.org/ is little confusing :)

Answer (score 2):

The broker declaration is needed if you want to run ActiveMQ [embedded](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-embed-a-broker-inside-a-connection.html) in your VM. You can use the connection factory as well to set up an embedded broker if you use the [vm-transport](http://activemq.apache.org/vm-transport-reference.html), albeit this offers limited configuration options for the broker.

The connection factory you need to, well, create new connections to a broker. Independent of whether it is embedded or runs externally. For that the factory needs to know where to connect to and what [transport](http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html) to use.